# 1972 textbook by Charles University professor on Thirty Years War

Tags: 17th-century, book, czech-republic

Just yesterday I came across a textbook citation on the [Thirty Years War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_years_war).

Here is what I (think I can) remember about the book in question: the author was professor at [Charles University in Prague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_University_in_Prague), his book was published in 1972 by Cambridge University Press, its cover blurb said that he analyzed new original sources that had surfaced from former noble estates, etc., to shine new light on the 17th-century period (presumably from a Marxist angle). The prof's name  perhaps started with a 'P' and ended with an 'y' (almost but not quite as e.g. in Pokorny).

Needless to say, I am today no longer able to trace that book and find it e.g. on amazon. Do you perhaps know the right full citation, or can you describe further leads?

I have read e.g. [Golo Mann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golo_Mann) on *[Wallenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albrecht_von_Wallenstein)*, and I plan to read [C.V. Wedgwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veronica_Wedgwood) for (presumably) a British view on these monumental events on the continent, so why not add another (again, presumably and from some angle) unconventional source as well.

Comment: +1 for C. V. Wedgwood's account.  It is a great book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Josef Polišenský suits quite well - he was a professor on Charles University, Thirty Years War was one of his topics and he published at least one book around that time. But his [The thirty years war](http://books.google.cz/books/about/The_thirty_years_war.html?id=YvXN_MPfJoEC&redir_esc=y) was published in 1971 by University of California Press. This is close enough to what you specified that it is very likely to be the hit.